# using javascript in .html form Magento2

Tags: magento2.2, javascript, jquery, requirejs

i have a custom form.html that displays at checkout.
i want to have a javascript tag - when the form load just show an alert testing purposes.

code i used below,

```
"<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
    $('document').ready(function(){
        console.log("this")
        alert('Load');
        document.getElementById('pinverify').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('labelBalance').style.display = "none";

        document.getElementById('payment[custom_field_one]').value =""; 
        document.getElementById('OTP').value= "";
        document.getElementById('payment[custom_field_three]').value = "";

   $('#verify').click(function(){

       checkOTPField();

    });
"
```

but this alias does not work, is there a different alias used in magento 2?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give the path to this .html file.

Comment: [namespace]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html

Comment: Can you describe your purpose?

Comment: i have created a custom form i have a textbox on the form aswell as a button i would like to run the javscript for that button within the html form $(button).click function - but its not allowing me to do that

Comment: Hey have you override this from (web/template/payment/form.html) from any core module? @RadhiyahWilliams

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you checked and do not have any error in your js code. Possible reason for the changes to not reflect is that you did not run the content:deploy command after making the changes:

Please run the below commands:

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```